# Monitoring solution for EC2 based deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring

We have some 20 or so servers in EC2, most are dynamically spawned (scaling groups).

We're looking for a solution to monitor the uptime of our application.

As an added bonus this solution could also extend to actually monitoring the servers involved so its easy to go back in time and see what happened just before a downtime or whatnot.

We're looking for a hosted solution ideally, and it should be easy to scale with it (it needs to somehow dynamically deal with servers being added/removed with no interaction from us).

Anyways, hoping for some recommendations from you guys.

---

A bit of background ...

We're currently using a custom Nagios setup, its been reduced to basically doing a simple http check now that the servers have become fully dynamic. We've already been using PagerDuty to deliver the pages. It does ok, but for the maintenance cost we could well be using a http check @ Server Density of Pingdom.

I've looked briefly at ServerDensity, and it does look promising, I especially like their install mechanism of just dumping their files into your AMI and it takes care of the rest.

I'd like to know what options there are tho before diving deeper into any particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

We use a combination of Server Density for monitoring and PagerDuty for alerting.  The two work quite well together.